# ODBC connection to OpenEdge 10.2B

Tags: odbc, windows-server-2003, openedge, progress-db

[image]I can't tune ODBC connection in ODBC Data Source Administrator using IP or host name of server. Only with localhost using.
Although I can successfully ping the server via IP or host name.
Firewall is tuned-of.

OpenEdge 10.2B is installed at Win Server 2003

The error I got:
[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify host name and port number ErrNum=10038[image]

Comment: You have shown the error.  But what connection string did you try to use that resulted in that error?

Comment: I tune ODBC connection via ODBC Data Source Administrator. Screenshot is attached

Comment: Progress OpenEdge 10.x is especially finicky about connection requests, demanding that clients use the same values as were used at instance launch. Look to the Progress `.lg` file (on the Progress server host), to confirm what the instance thinks its `-H` (hostname) and `-S` (service) properties are.

Answer (score 0):

I am sssuming you clicked "Test Connect"?  Is your database really named TEMP?  That seems unlikely.

"Administrator" is also an unusual name for a user of the db.  "sysprogress" is more typical (although you should certainly setup a non-default userid.)

So far you have shown roughly half of the configuration required to make this work.  Your DSN setup isn't obviously wrong but if it does not match a running database that is listening on port 3333 at that IP address then you will get this error.

The next  useful thing that you could do to clarify the problem is to show the database configuration and demonstrate that you have a properly configured broker running and listening for connections on port 3333.

Answer (score 0):

check list：

1、you must start your openEdge database

```
$DLC/bin/_mprosrv {database-full-path}    -L 8000 -c 350 -B 1000 -N TCP -S {Port} -n 100
```

2、check Firewalls rule

3、use userID : SYSPROGRESS password ：SYSPROGRESS to test odbc connect